# Get last saved row in my database every fixed time period and update view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am developing ASP.NET web application project that uses azure sql database. This is my code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var item = getLastRecord();
                var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
                var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

                var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
                {
                    item = getLastRecord();
                }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

                return View(item);
            }
        }

        public call_off getLastRecord()
        {
            var item = db.call_off.OrderByDescending(x => x.millis).First();
            return (item);
        }
```

I need to always check my table and get the last record entered. For example i made a timer that excutes a function every 1 min and gets the last saved row but it is not working. I need the value to be automatically updated every certain time span and my view gets updated then without the need to refresh the whole website.
Any help?

Comment: there are multiple ways to solve your problem, but the optimum way is using `SignalR`library. for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622508/how-can-i-automatically-update-a-partial-view

Comment: I think you can use ajax timer function to refresh your page at some time. For more details, please refer to https://makitweb.com/how-to-fire-ajax-request-on-regular-interval/